# Why is Abu Huraira considered unreliable by Shia fiqh?

Tags: fiqh, shiism, uloom-al-hadith

I have **[seen](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16656)** that Abu Huraira is considered as an unreliable narrator by Shia:

> One famous example would be the case of Abu Hurayrah, who narrated
>   over five thousand hadiths: Sunnis consider him a reliable source,
>   Shi'ites do not, and his case is not unique.

Why?

Comment: Maybe relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35720/are-there-narration-chains-for-the-coccyx-tailbone-hadith-that-dont-go-through, http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37623/hadith-of-abu-huraira-throat-being-cut and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28346/why-abu-hurraira-changed-his-narration ...

Answer (score 4):

[Not being a Shia myself, if someone sees a mistake here please edit and rectify it].

The Jafaris\Imamis do not consider Abu Hurairah to be a reliable narrator, because they have a narration from [Imam Jafar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) to the effect:

> سمعت جعفر بن محمد عليهما السلام يقول: ثلاثة كانوا يكذبون على رسول
> الله أبو هريرة، وأنس بن مالك، وامرأة
>
> Jafar bin Muhammad said: Three people told lies about the Messenger of
> Allah: Abu Hurairah, Anas bin Malik and the woman.
>
> <sub>— [Al-Khisal by Sheikh Saduq, p190](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1137_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D9%8A%D8%AE-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%82/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_204)</sub>

Comment: It is a nice brief answer. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Comment: maybe it is "the women"? else, who is "the woman"?

Comment: now, i assume it ("the woman") is aisha

Answer (score 3):

```
                                   بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

In order to elucidate the issue, of note, there can be diverse reasons/evidences for rejecting him (and in order to prove everyone, there need long discussion and documents... but here I just mention some of the reasons in short, hopefully can help you).

- Ali (a.s.) and some of Sahabas protested him owing to ... (apart from
  Umar's protest who ...) Ref.: ابوزرعه، ج۱، ص۵۴۴  and  ر.ک: ابن قتیبه،
  تاویل، ص۲۸؛ ابن سعد، ج۴، ص۳۳۲؛ بسوی، ج۱، ص۴۸۶
- Owing to the relationship/paradox between his hadiths/its numbers and
  the time of ... with the Prophet. (sorry for incomplete illustration,
  so, in order to have a detailed evaluating you can refer to the
  source --if you are familiar to Arabic or Farsi [Persian]--)
- As another related reason, (from another aspect which can be regarded for Shia Islam too: Bukhari, Muslim, Dhahabi, Imam Abu Ja’far Iskafi, Muttaqi Hindi and
  others have reported that the second khalifah, whipped Abu-Hurairah
  as a result of him going too far in forging hadiths from the Prophet
  (pbuh) and strongly prohibited him from narrating any more till the
  end of his reign. The reason behind this can be found in the
  following:

1- His companionship with Ka'b al-Ahbar the Jew, and
   narrating from him.

2- Him narrating hollow hadiths which usually
   would convey what the Israiliyyat hadiths (unauthentic and forged
   hadiths by the Jews or under the influence of them that cause
   distortion in Islamic tradition, history and tafsir and bring into
   religion fraud beliefs) conveyed, and in reality, were the Israliyyat
   themselves.

3- Narrating hadiths that were the opposite of ones
   narrated by the Sahabas. Imam Ali (as) and Abu Bakr opposing him.

And so on.

**Of note, I strived to point out a part of the reasons to reject him, otherwise there can be more reasons to elucidate/persuade it.**

---

Reference:

- [www.islamquest.net](http://%20-%20http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa1274)
- [ar.wikishia.net](http://%20-%20http://ar.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D9%87%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A9)
- [fa.wikishia.net](http://%20-%20http://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%87%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%B1%D9%87#cite_ref-34)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://%20-%20http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/id23187)